# SUM all values of an array of objects by array index of object property in JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like this

```
[
   {Ref: "A", Vals: [1,2,3,100]},
   {Ref: "B", Vals: [1,2,3,100]},
   {Ref: "C", Vals: [1,2,3,100]}
]
```

I want to produce an array which is the sum of B and C (Not A) by index, so the result would be

[2,4,6,200]

I can do this using multiple loops as follows:

```
var output= [];
var filteredArray = $.grep(arr, function (v) {
            return v.Ref !== "A";
        });

$.each(filteredArray, function (i, v) {
  $.each(v.Vals, function (i, v) {
       output[i] += v;
  });
```

});

But this seems quite long winded and inefficient. Is there a more elegant / efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: This smells a bit like a homework question, which probably explains the downvotes. Have you already tried figuring out a method to do this? Was there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, have added my attempt to question, which Im not entirely happy with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an array of `Ref` values for those `Vals` that you want to include in the calculation and then use `reduce` and `find` to get the an array with correct calculation.

```js
const data = [{Ref: "A", Vals: [1,2,3,100]}, {Ref: "B", Vals: [1,2,3,100]}, {Ref: "C", Vals: [1,2,3,100]}]


const result = ['A', 'C'].reduce((r, e) => {
  const match = data.find(({ Ref }) => Ref === e);

  if (match) {
    if (!r) r = match.Vals
    else match.Vals.forEach((el, i) => r[i] += el)
  }

  return r
}, null)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a filter, followed by a map (to only pick out the `Vals`), and then use a reduce on that filtered/mapped array.

```
input.filter(obj => {
  return obj.Ref !== "A"
}).map(obj => {
  return obj.Vals
}).reduce((carry, obj) => {
  if (!carry) { return obj }

  // This bit could be optimised more, right now it fails if the
  // 'Vals' differ in length.
  var response = carry

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    response[i] += obj[i]
  }

  return response
})
```